# Tic-Tac-Toe AI minimax function in Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have here my code for the minimax algorithm. It seems to be making smart decisions, but not always, which shouldn't be happening and I need help because I can't seem to find where I went wrong.

```
private char level2Move() {
  try {
    NBoard game_copy = (NBoard) game.clone();

    int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    char bestMove = '-';

    for (char move: game_copy.getValidMoves()) {
      game_copy.enterMove(move);
      int score = minimax(game_copy, true);
      game_copy.undoMove();
      if (score > bestScore) {
        bestScore = score;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    }

    return bestMove;
  } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return '-';
}
```

```
public int minimax(NBoard game, boolean isMaximizing) {
  int bestScore;

  switch (game.getGameState()) {
  case NBoard.X_WIN:
    return - 10;
  case NBoard.O_WIN:
    return 10;
  case NBoard.DRAW:
    return 0;
  }

  if (isMaximizing) {
    bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (char move: game.getValidMoves()) {
      if (game.getGameState() == NBoard.ONGOING) {
        game.enterMove(move);
        int score = minimax(game, false);
        game.undoMove();
        bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
      }
    }
  } else {
    bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (char move: game.getValidMoves()) {
      if (game.getGameState() == NBoard.ONGOING) {
        game.enterMove(move);
        int score = minimax(game, true);
        game.undoMove();
        bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
      }
    }
  }
  return bestScore;
}
```

Board input (move) are letters A-I, like so...

```
A|B|C
D|E|F
G|H|I
```

I seem to have not used "score" yet and am thinking of adding depth, but I can't think of how that would help.

Comment: Are you sure you calculate WDL correctly? If it sometimes makes good moves it seems like it makes random moves, or always chose the first move it tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Simply changed the boolean values in the minimax function.

```
private char level2Move() {
  try {
    NBoard game_copy = (NBoard) game.clone();

    int bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    char bestMove = '-';

    for (char move: game_copy.getValidMoves()) {
      game_copy.enterMove(move);
      int score = minimax(game_copy, false);       // here
      game_copy.undoMove();
      if (score > bestScore) {
        bestScore = score;
        bestMove = move;
      }
    }

    return bestMove;
  } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return '-';
}
```

```
public int minimax(NBoard game, boolean isMaximizing) {
  int bestScore;

  switch (game.getGameState()) {
  case NBoard.X_WIN:
    return - 10;
  case NBoard.O_WIN:
    return 10;
  case NBoard.DRAW:
    return 0;
  }

  if (isMaximizing) {
    bestScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (char move: game.getValidMoves()) {
      if (game.getGameState() == NBoard.ONGOING) {
        game.enterMove(move);
        int score = minimax(game, false);          // here
        game.undoMove();
        bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
      }
    }
  } else {
    bestScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (char move: game.getValidMoves()) {
      if (game.getGameState() == NBoard.ONGOING) {
        game.enterMove(move);
        int score = minimax(game, true);           // here
        game.undoMove();
        bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
      }
    }
  }
  return bestScore;
}
```